# Адаптер для RecyclerView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Есть БД из которой данные будут выводиться в RecyclerView. Также есть активность где пользователь может добавить запись из БД в избранное или удалить из избранного (пометка 1 или 0 в таблице из БД) при этом необходимо чтобы изменения сразу отображались в RecyclerView.. Есть ли какой-нибудь Адаптер для recyclerview наподобие CursorAdapter для ListView, если есть скиньте пожалуйста ссылки на примеры.

P.S. А то через коллекции выводить записи из БД в recyclerview как оказалось совсем не то

P.S. сейчас использую RecyclerView.Adapter

Answer (score 1):

Берите и пользуйтесь: [RecyclerCursorAdapter](https://github.com/brianwernick/RecyclerExt/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/devbrackets/android/recyclerext/adapter/RecyclerCursorAdapter.java)

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот еще один самодельный `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter`, который был найден на просторах enSO — [страница GitHub](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59). Ему на вход передается `Cursor`. В этом ответе на enSO еще много вариантов — [страница](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517855/using-the-recyclerview-with-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать Realm, он позволяет вешать слушателя на изменения в объекте.

Собственно сам объект:

```
    final RealmResults<Dog> puppies = realm.where(Dog.class)..findAll();
    puppies.size(); // => 0
```

И слушатель который отслеживает изменения в нем:

```
    puppies.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Dog> results) {
      // results and puppies point are both up to date
      results.size(); // => 1

    }
});
```

В слушателе вызываете `notifyDataSetChanged`

UPD: Realm не уступает по скорости Sqlite и вполне может послужить его заменой

Comment: официальный адаптер для realm поддерживает автообновление списка при изменении данных, нет необходимости делать это в ручную