# Приложение с RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь написать свое первое приложение для андроид и прошу вашей помощи. Решила написать приложение с рецептами блюд. Есть БД с таблицами блюд и категорий. Для вывода самих блюд решила использовать RecyclerView.

Подскажите мне Какой адаптер использовать для RecyclerView, чтобы работать с БД через этот адаптер? На картинке ниже примерный вид приложения

Оно должно уметь следующее:

1. Вывести в RecyclerView блюда
2. Сверху есть иконка поиска. При нажатии на поиск чтобы в списке оставались только те блюда, которые соответствуют запросу

Пожалуйста не отсылайте на различные сайты где реализовано не совсем то что мне нужно. Если и даете ссылки, то пожалуйста на такой же пример как в моем случае. Всем заранее спасибо большое.

P.S. Если в БД произошли какие-то изменения, т.е. изменилось описание блюда, отметили блюдо как любимое или т.д. эти изменения немедленно должны отображаться в списке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий, фактически готовое приложение. Разбейте его на несколько с локальными проблемами, которые вы не можете решить и на который можно дать лаконичный ответ разумнгого объема. Вопрос о [БД с избранным и фильтром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345). Адаптер  для [БД с RecyclerView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709772/177345)

Comment: Я читала про это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709772/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-recyclerview  но не смогла разобраться как работает данный адаптер

Comment: Как и все адаптеры. Конкретно этот получает на вход выборку Cursor из БД и выводит ее в список. Не нужно здесь задавать вопросы, как написать приложение с избранным и поиском в подробностях, на него все равно никто отвечать не будет (или в лучшем случае общий ответ), так как это не формат данного ресурса. Задавайте вопросы по каждой ступени, напишите вопрос, как вы пытались использовать данный адаптер, в чем именно проблема, что не получилось, приведите код.